# Proper use of target_include_directories() in CMake

Tags: cmake

I`m refactoring a CMake project. I wanted to include pre-compiled third-party .dll library into custom shared library, but have difficulties with populating headers files.

Project structure:

```
CMakeListst.txt

app
    CMakeLists.txt

modules
    my-library
        include
        CMakeLists.txt
        
    ...

third-party // precompiled, non-CMake
    third-party.dll
    include
    
build
    modules
        my-library
            my-library.dll
            include

    app
            app.exe
```

I have a third-party library ("third-party"), which I want to include into "my-library". So CMakeLists for "my-library" looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project("my-library" VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(PUBLIC_HEADERS
    include/my-library.h
)

set(SOURCES
    my-library.cpp
)

add_library("my-library" SHARED ${PUBLIC_HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries("my-library" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/third-party.dll")
target_include_directories("my-library" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/include")

target_include_directories("my-library" PUBLIC include)
```

And then add "my-library" to the app like this:

```
target_include_directories("app" PRIVATE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/my-library/include")
target_link_libraries("app" PRIVATE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules/my-library/my-library.dll")
```

But I get 'No such file or directory #include "third-party.h"'. In other words, app has no access to third-party inlcude directory.
Though it can be fixed by copying "include" of third-party to "include" of my-library,
is doesn`t look like a correct method. Or is it how includes supposed to be used? What am I missing here? I had a perception, that unlike include_directories() target_include_directories() should export included path.

Comment: Neither `.lib` nor `.dll` file contains headers or information about include directories. That is, if you want to include a header in your `app`, then given header should exist and its directory should be specified as include one.

Comment: It is not clear from your description, whether your `app` is built from the same invocation of cmake, which builds your `my-library`? If yes, then you are better to link with the library **target** (`my-library`), not with the library *file* (`.dll`).

Comment: Well, yes it`s the same invokation of cmake. I will try it. And back to my question - is manually copying headers from "third-party" include directory to "my-library" inlude directory is OK?
And target_include_directories() will not do it by itself?

Comment: "is manually copying headers from "third-party" include directory to "my-library" inlude directory is OK?" - OK for **what**? What is a purpose of that copiing? If you build all libraries and executables in the **same project**, then I see no reason to copy headers. "And target_include_directories() will not do it by itself?" - `target_include_directories` copies nothing. This command just adds appropriate flag to the compiler (e.g. `/I` for MSVC) which specifies the include directory.

Comment: Ok, it was a typo - I did not expect target_include_directory() to actually copy something. My initial problem - if I use only target_include_directories(), compiler can`t see theese headers. So it looks like, that target_include_directory() did nothing at all.

Comment: do as @Tsyvarev says.  `target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE my-library)`.  That will transitively pull in the include path.